# PHP settings seems to always load as variable my POST data?

Tags: php

I just notice Netfirms changed all their server settings and I now have a bug with a simple script and was wondering what is the server setting for PHP that was causing this?

Basically, I have a FORM that POST data, for example `<input name='DATA1' value="5">`

My problem is that when I send the form, the page that receive the form seem to `automatically` assign `DATA1` POST value to a variable named `$DATA1`.

Why is that and how to do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is very insecure, but the setting that you have to change in `php.ini` is [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals).

Please note that register_globals cannot be set at runtime (`ini_set()`), although you can use .htaccess if your host allows it as described above.

An example `.htaccess` entry: `php_flag register_globals off`.

Comment: Thanks! It was the problem. This is something I so never touched that I did not remember about it :)

Comment: Don't mention it.. glad I could help :-)